# Avoiding multiple verification for Twitter API (node.js)

Tags: node.js, twitter

I'm trying to create a basic app in node.js that a) tracks a keyword in twitter and temporarily stores messages relating to that keyword, b) after enough messages have been accumulated, return it to the user. I'm using the ntwitter library.

I've a basic long polling system implemented on my client and server side, but I'm having some trouble on verification. The way I set it up currently, it verifies the user each time /api/streamfeed is called, so potentially every 30sec (since I have a 30s timeout schedule) before checking the stream. I'm thinking this will get me into trouble since I believe verification is rate-limited? Is there a way to check whether I'm verified without having to ping Twitter's API (perhaps store a boolean after the first attempt)?

Client side:

```
//upon receiving a response, poll again
function getStreamFeed() {
  console.log('calling getStreamFeed');
  $http.get('/api/streamfeed').success(function(data) {
    console.log(data)
    getStreamFeed();
  });
};

setTimeout(getStreamFeed, 1000);


Server side:
app.get('/api/streamfeed', function(req, res) {
    /* 
        ...
        polling code
        ...
    */

    twit.verifyCredentials(function(err, data) {
      if (err) res.send(404);
      twit.stream('statuses/filter', {
        track: 'justin bieber'
      }, function(stream) {
        stream.on('data', function(data) {
          console.log(data.text)
          messages.push(data.text);
        });

      })
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd send the credentials back and resend them again... this could be a bool, or actual credentials to use. these aren't your private keys or anything, only the user's.

could also be sent in headers and cookies and properly hashed etc.

this just simply shows a pattern that should work.

client side:

```
function getStreamFeed(credentials) {
    //upon receiving a response, poll again
    console.log('calling getStreamFeed');
    var url = '/api/streamfeed';
    if (credentials) {
        url += '&credentials=' + credentials;
    }
    $http
        .get(url)
        .success(function(data) {
            console.log(data)
            getStreamFeed(true);
        });
};

setTimeout(getStreamFeed, 1000);
```

Server side:

```
app.get('/api/streamfeed', function(req, res) {
    function twitStream () {
        twit.stream('statuses/filter', {track: 'justin bieber'}, function(stream) {
            stream.on('data', function(data) {
                console.log(data.text)
                messages.push(data.text);
            });
        }
    }
    var credentials = req.query.credentials;
    if (credentials) {
        twitStream()
    }
    twit.verifyCredentials(function(err, data) {
        if (err) res.send(404);
        twitStream()
    });
});
```