# Are global variables in node.js server wide or just for that session or user

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a very basic question and apologise if it is dumb - are global variables in node.js server-wide or is it just for that session or user? For instance, I'm thinking of creating a global boolean variable under a routes.js file to store whether twitter credentials have been verified, and if it has, then it shouldn't re-verify.

However, I'm wondering whether the variable will be created for every single session/user or will it be created once for the entire server (i.e. if one person verifies, which sets verifiedCredentials to true, will the variable be true for all other users?).

```
routes.js (Server side):
'use strict';

var verifiedCredentials = false;

/**
 * Application routes
 */
module.exports = function(app) {

  // Server API Routes
  app.get('/api/awesomeThings', function(req, res) {
    if (!verifiedCredentials) {
      //do some verification
      verifiedCredentials = true;
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not so hard to test that.

But as you didn't, here's the result : global variables are really global, there's no session/user context in the core of node.

In fact node isn't really a http server program, it's an event based engine on which you can run many things and which happens to be often used to run http based applications (but it can be used for applications for which there's not even a notion of session or user).

If you do need to attach variables to sessions, then, as you're using express, just ask it to manage sessions and store your variable as in

```
req.session.verifiedCredentials = false;
```

Note that if you're trying to manage authentication, as your variable name lets think, you might be interested by already tested modules doing it, for example [passport](http://passportjs.org/).

Comment: Hi @dystroy, thank you for the great tips, and it's really useful! I'm not doing traditional authentication per se. I'm using ntwitter's stream functionality, and I'm calling it every 30s or so and I'm trying to avoid verifying my credentials multiple times. Hence I was thinking of using a session variable of sorts to store that to avoid having to constantly verify and running into the rate limit. I'll probably just use a session variable as you suggested I think. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23828383/avoiding-multiple-verification-for-twitter-api-node-js